# Can Tacx Flow head unit work with old (2002) Basic frame/brake?

Tags: trainer, compatibility, turbo-trainer

I want to replace a lost head unit/computer on my old Tacx Basic from 2002, does anybody know if modern Flow head unit will work with this old frame/load generator? I think such was an upgrade path, once, but still - the frame is really old (but in good working condition).

Comment: I do not know the answer to your question but I have a 2005 Tacx Flow and the load generator for that year was the same as the load generator for the Tacx I-Magic and the Tacx Grand Excel -- and in previous years the Grand Excel and the Basic used the same load generator. The question then, of course, is whether the Grand Excel's load generator changed between 2002 and 2005.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in a comment on the question, the load generator for the Tacx Basic in the early 2000's was the same load generator used across the entire Tacx ergometer line. The Basic, the Grand Excel, the Flow, and the I-Magic all used the same load generator, so the head units are interchangeable. The capabilities of the Basic can thus be "upgraded" by switching to a Grand Excel or I-Magic head unit (the Flow replaced the Basic in the Tacx line in 2004 or 2005 and, except for a larger screen and slightly easier calibration procedure the models are equivalent).